# Quantization of Conv Layer for Tensorflow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I am currently trying to quantize a model to speed up its inference on an edge device (Coral Edge or I.MX8).

In its documentation [I.MX ML Guide](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/IMX-MACHINE-LEARNING-UG.pdf) I followed the Tensorflow Lite path since it is strongly advised to use this framework for inference on the I.MX8 NPU and Coral TPU.

Since my work is about Pose-Estimation, I successfully converted the [Openpose-Lite](https://github.com/Daniil-Osokin/lightweight-human-pose-estimation.pytorch) Pytorch model to Tensorflow Lite via openvino and applied full integer quantization on it, as required by both edge devices.

(The models for Openpose Lite are available (7 Days from now) on [this Link](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20221020yn41SjU6))

Comparing the inference speed of the quantized model, to the available (already optimized) [Posenet](https://github.com/google-coral/project-posenet) models on the I.MX8 NPU and the TPU, I received the following results.

| Accelerator | Posenet | Openpose Lite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I.MX8 NPU | 9 ms | **160 ms** |
| Coral Edge TPU | 9 ms | 34.5 ms |

Since the Openpose Lite network is bigger (in size and Conv-Operations) by a factor 2-3 I would also expect such a behaviour reflected on the inference time. The inference on the NPU is therefore rather slow.

Comparing the networks in [Netron](https://netron.app/) also showing strange differences. For example, the optimized posenet model seems to use no activation after their convolutions. Furthermore it seems that the convolution in posenet are quantized layer wise, whereas in openpose it is quantized channel wise.

The main questions therefore are :

1. How can posenet be so much faster than openpose lite on the NPU?
2. <s>How can one achieve Layer wise quantization on the TFLite conversion for the Conv Layers? (if this is the problem after all)</s>
3. <s>Why are there no activation layers (they must be there, otherwise it would not have learned) in the posenet models visible in netron? Are they hidden by the use of a custom operator?</s>

Thanks for your help.

Edit 1 Conv Layer Quantization :

```
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.quantization.keras import quantizers
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

class Default8BitQuantizeConfig(tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig):
  """QuantizeConfig for non recurrent Keras layers."""

  def __init__(self, weight_attrs, activation_attrs, quantize_output):
    self.weight_attrs = weight_attrs
    self.activation_attrs = activation_attrs
    self.quantize_output = quantize_output

    # TODO(pulkitb): For some layers such as Conv2D, per_axis should be True.
    # Add mapping for which layers support per_axis.
    self.weight_quantizer = quantizers.LastValueQuantizer(
        num_bits=8, per_axis=False, symmetric=True, narrow_range=True)
    self.activation_quantizer = quantizers.MovingAverageQuantizer(
        num_bits=8, per_axis=False, symmetric=False, narrow_range=False)

  def get_weights_and_quantizers(self, layer):
    return [(getattr(layer, weight_attr), self.weight_quantizer)
            for weight_attr in self.weight_attrs]

  def get_activations_and_quantizers(self, layer):
    return [(getattr(layer, activation_attr), self.activation_quantizer)
            for activation_attr in self.activation_attrs]

  def set_quantize_weights(self, layer, quantize_weights):
    if len(self.weight_attrs) != len(quantize_weights):
      raise ValueError(
          '`set_quantize_weights` called on layer {} with {} '
          'weight parameters, but layer expects {} values.'.format(
              layer.name, len(quantize_weights), len(self.weight_attrs)))

    for weight_attr, weight in zip(self.weight_attrs, quantize_weights):
      current_weight = getattr(layer, weight_attr)
      if current_weight.shape != weight.shape:
        raise ValueError('Existing layer weight shape {} is incompatible with'
                         'provided weight shape {}'.format(
                             current_weight.shape, weight.shape))

      setattr(layer, weight_attr, weight)

  def set_quantize_activations(self, layer, quantize_activations):
    if len(self.activation_attrs) != len(quantize_activations):
      raise ValueError(
          '`set_quantize_activations` called on layer {} with {} '
          'activation parameters, but layer expects {} values.'.format(
              layer.name, len(quantize_activations),
              len(self.activation_attrs)))

    for activation_attr, activation in \
        zip(self.activation_attrs, quantize_activations):
      setattr(layer, activation_attr, activation)

  def get_output_quantizers(self, layer):
    if self.quantize_output:
      return [self.activation_quantizer]
    return []

  @classmethod
  def from_config(cls, config):
    """Instantiates a `Default8BitQuantizeConfig` from its config.
    Args:
        config: Output of `get_config()`.
    Returns:
        A `Default8BitQuantizeConfig` instance.
    """
    return cls(**config)

  def get_config(self):
    # TODO(pulkitb): Add weight and activation quantizer to config.
    # Currently it's created internally, but ideally the quantizers should be
    # part of the constructor and passed in from the registry.
    return {
        'weight_attrs': self.weight_attrs,
        'activation_attrs': self.activation_attrs,
        'quantize_output': self.quantize_output
    }

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Default8BitQuantizeConfig):
      return False

    return (self.weight_attrs == other.weight_attrs and
            self.activation_attrs == self.activation_attrs and
            self.weight_quantizer == other.weight_quantizer and
            self.activation_quantizer == other.activation_quantizer and
            self.quantize_output == other.quantize_output)

  def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
  
class Default8BitConvWeightsQuantizer(quantizers.LastValueQuantizer):
  """Quantizer for handling weights in Conv2D/DepthwiseConv2D layers."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Construct LastValueQuantizer with params specific for TFLite Convs."""

    super(Default8BitConvWeightsQuantizer, self).__init__(
        num_bits=8, per_axis=False, symmetric=True, narrow_range=True)

  def build(self, tensor_shape, name, layer):
    min_weight = layer.add_weight(
        name + '_min',
        shape=None,
        initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(-6.0),
        trainable=False)
    max_weight = layer.add_weight(
        name + '_max',
        shape=None,
        initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(6.0),
        trainable=False)

    return {'min_var': min_weight, 'max_var': max_weight}
  
class CustomDefault8BitConvQuantizeConfig(Default8BitQuantizeConfig):
  """QuantizeConfig for Conv2D/DepthwiseConv2D layers."""

  def __init__(self, weight_attrs, activation_attrs, quantize_output):
    super(CustomDefault8BitConvQuantizeConfig,
          self).__init__(weight_attrs, activation_attrs, quantize_output)

    self.weight_quantizer = Default8BitConvWeightsQuantizer()
    

def setup_model():
  quantize_annotate_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_model
  quantize_annotate_layer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer
  model = quantize_annotate_model(tf.keras.Sequential([
        quantize_annotate_layer(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3),input_shape=(28, 28, 1), padding = 'same', activation='relu')),
        quantize_annotate_layer(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation='relu'),quantize_config=CustomDefault8BitConvQuantizeConfig(['kernel'], ['activation'],True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
       tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
  ]))
  quantize_scope = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_scope
  with quantize_scope(
    {'CustomDefault8BitConvQuantizeConfig': CustomDefault8BitConvQuantizeConfig}):
    # Use `quantize_apply` to actually make the model quantization aware.
    quant_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_apply(model)
  return quant_aware_model
```

Comment: When there are no activations, the model will not learn much. Without activations, any number of conv layers is exactly the same as just one layer

Comment: Hello @AndrzejO, I know, this is the reason why I am suspicious. I guess netron cant read it correctly, but I want to know the reason.